# Detecting Karma's runner mode from the browser

Tags: javascript, testing, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

Karma has two runner modes in the browser: default and debug (`/debug.html`). There are differences in how the two modes operate. For example, in debug mode you can `console.log` objects with circular references. In default mode this generates a JSON circular reference error.

Is there a mechanism to detect which mode Karma is in from JS so that, for example, additional error logging is activated in debug mode?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you kind of answered this yourself ...

```
var isDebug = !!document.URL.match(/debug\.html/)
```

Any reason this would not work for you?

Comment: This will work but it's fragile as it depends on a Karma implementation detail, which can change. I wish the Karma team designed this into their API.